# Error C2131 using switch and case statements

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

When compiling the following code, I get this error message:

Error   C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant

this appears on all the 'case' lines e.g

```
case  (x == 10):
```

this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int x;

    cout << "Please enter your value for x" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "The value you entered for x is " << x << endl;

    switch (x)
    {
        case  (x == 10) :

        {
            x = x + 10;
            cout << "x is " << x << endl;
        }

        case (x == 20) :

        {
            x = x + 20;
            cout << "x is " << x << endl;
        }

        case (x == 30) :
        {
            x = x + 30;
            cout << "x is " << x << endl;
        }

        case:

        {
            cout << "x is " << 2 * x << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I realise I must be using the switch statement incorrectly, could someone please set me straight ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to look at any example code? Any tutorial or book on C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `case` just looks like `case 10:`. Putting a variable (not a constant expression) in the case will give you an error, as the values for the cases need to be known when the code is compiled. Also, if you don't put `break` at the end of a `case`, it'll chain through all the other statements until it hits a break or the end of the `switch`. For example, the following code would display `12`;

```
switch (1)
{
case 1:
    cout << "1";
case 2:
    cout << "2";
break;
case 3:
    cout << "3";
}
```

If you want to handle any value that you don't have a case for, use `default`, not an empty case.

```
switch (x)
{
    //case statements
default:
    cout << x * 2;
}
```